# IF-sentence over all columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, lapply

I have a df, I would like R to paste 'Hi,' in front of the text, if a condition is fulfilled (if the column contains 'how are you').

```
t <- data.frame('x1' = c('how are you','whats up?', 'whats up?'), "x2" = c('how are you','how are you', 'whats up?'), "x3" = c('whats up?','how are you', 'whats up?'))
```

How can I do it for all the columns at the same time?
I have tried with an if-sentence and lapply

```
#this doesn't work

t[] <- if(t[] %like% ('how are you')) {paste("Hi, ",t[])}

t[] <- lapply(t, function(x)  if(x %like% ('how are you')) {paste("Hi,",x)})

#this works, but then all other content is erased;

t[] <- lapply(t, function(x) 
                ifelse(x %like% ('how are you'), paste("Hi,", x),""))
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grepl` if you want to do a pattern match

```
t[] <- lapply(t, function(x) ifelse(grepl('how are you', x), paste('Hi', x), x))
```

Or use `==` for an exact match.

```
t[] <- lapply(t, function(x) ifelse(x == 'how are you', paste('Hi', x), x))
t

#              x1             x2             x3
#1 Hi how are you Hi how are you      whats up?
#2      whats up? Hi how are you Hi how are you
#3      whats up?      whats up?      whats up?
```